# Can I tell GNOME to ignore mounts in my home directory?

Tags: gnome, mount

I work on a software project who's build system creates a number of bind mounts.  Unfortunately, when I run this build system on a 20.10 system, GNOME crashes and takes the session out.  Any further attempt to create a graphical session crashes almost immediately until I unmount the bind mounts.

I think GNOME is trying to treat the bind mounts as though they were removable devices.

Can I tell it to ignore mounts it finds in a particular path?  Ideally it would ignore anything in my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my opnion it related to gfvs.

Add in /etc/fstab to your bind mounts option

```
x-gvfs-hide
```

This removes in my case the entries under devices, in focal (lubuntu) with default filemnanager (pcmanfm-qt).

Comment: This would be an option if the mounts were in fstab.  They aren't, they're created by the build system.  `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false` fixed this for me.